# Is there a way to find a node by number in LTspice?

Tags: simulation, ltspice

I'm looking for a way to find a particular node, based on the auto-generated node name/number.

One way to find a particular node is to hover the cursor over the nodes, and LTspice will put the name in the status bar at the bottom (see image).

[image: LTspice screenshot]

If I have a large circuit with 500+ nodes, and maybe only 10 or so have actual names/labels, it would take a long time to hover over all the nodes in search of one in particular.

How can I find "Node N004" without hovering over all of the nodes?
Is there a way to show the names of all nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually there's an easier way.... I never thought in simply trying Ctrl+F on the main window hahaha. That's all you have to do! Ctrl+F on the circuit and a search box will appear. You can search nodes and components there. I just tried. Example:

[image]

Does exactly what @jonk was hoping to find: highlight the node. Not sure why this is now shown on the submenus or on the Hot Keys section of Settings. If it is on the submenus, I don't find it. And I found the shortcut by accident. Didn't know what happened for that to appear. Until I tried the most simple shortcut and it worked xD.

Comment: Oh that's handy! I wonder if this is a new feature since jonk's answer.

Comment: Nope. Just tried in LTspiceIV (installed it now). Outdated 1600 days (4.4 years) by the updates notifier. It already existed! But not like this: what happens when you Ctrl+F in Netlist happened in IV (a small window). So at least by 2016 it already existed (before jonk's answer then). Pity it's not put somewhere visible (or more visible, in case it's already noted somewhere, like in the Help?), so people can know the shortcut actually exists.

Comment: LTspice is known for its spartan help file, and this is one of those cases where you can only see a reference in the `Tools > Colour Preferences`, as the colour of the highlighted node. Good answer but, otherwise, this is quite old news, I'm afraid. :-)

Comment: The thing is I knew there was an highlight feature (I went there to change the colors as I have in the picture). I just didn't know what it was supposed to do and how to use it. And from what I just confirmed, I can't see any tip there to use Ctrl+F. So when I found about that highlight thing, I just got curious and then the curiosity went away, since I had no idea what it was supposed to do. Maybe this might help others link me who had no idea how to highlight the things (or who didn't even know about the highlight feature haha).

Comment: This is incredible news! I must re-crown the best answer to DADi590 (Sorry Sir Jonk). You're off to a good start here DADi590!

Answer (score 8):

Select the schematic (just click on it to make sure it is "current") and then go to View/Spice Netlist. That should pop up a nice text box of your circuit. You can then hit ctrl-F to do a find (search) for your node. (Just enter the node name into the "find" box.) From that, you can easily find each associated part that mentions the node, thereby finding all of the resistors, capacitors, etc., and their designations (names.) Now knowing all the parts that connect to that node, this might make it a little easier for you when going back to look at the schematic.

It certainly helps me. If I know that R29, R31, C12, and Q4 all reference that node, then I usually can find the node in short order.

I don't know of a way to cause the node to highlight itself, by name, though.

Comment: Hi. If you're still interested in knowing how to highlight the node, please see my answer bellow (if you don't already know by now). Just thought I could tell you about it.